# SFTP Chroot write in chrooted /

Tags: linux, debian, sftp, directory, chroot

**Hey**,

I'd like to write with the chrooted user in his / but i can't.

Example: i have `/home/sftponly/` as ChrootDirectory

Inside has to be another Directory with Permissions to this User, otherwise i cant connect.

I want it to be writable while the user that connects doesen't see any Sub-Dir. Any Tips on what i'm doing wrong?

My sshd_config

```
Match User sftponly
  ChrootDirectory /home/sftponly
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at your filesystem-permissions and chmod?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your user to be able to write to his home directory while being chrooted.

What happens when you connect using sftp with chroot enabled is like this:

- the user is chrooted to the main "chroot" directory (here, `/home/sftponly`)

  - the main chroot must be owned by root and read-only for the users.
- the user is then chrooted *again* into his home directory as described in `/etc/passwd` starting from the main chroot. *This* home directory can be writeable to the user.

So if in /etc/passwd you have a line such as this:

```
sftponly:x:1002:1002:,,,:/home/sftponly:/bin/bash
```

sshd will try to chroot your user into `/home/sftponly/home/sftponly`.

So if you *absolutely need* to chroot to this precise path `/home/sftponly` you must set your main chroot in `sshd_config` to, for instance, `/home`:

```
ChrootDirectory /home
```

Then set the home directory of *sftponly* in `/etc/passwd` to `/sftponly` :

```
sftponly:x:1002:1002::/sftponly:/bin/bash
```

Then `/home/sftponly` can be writeable for the sftponly user, no problem.

Comment: Okay perfect this worked for me! BUT like you said, the User can go back to /home, do you know any Software that allows me to lock him in in / and make it writeable for him?

Comment: @roseroserh no the chroot is always read-only, this is by design. This applies to SFTP, FTP, etc.